# Multi-input monadic functions with currying in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads, currying

I have a function like so

```
foo :: X -> Y -> Z
```

and I have two separate calculations that are done to get my variables of type `X` and `Y`, but they can fail, so I use a Maybe

```
calc1 :: A -> Maybe X
calc2 :: B -> Maybe Y
```

now I am not sure how to use the monad operations to get this desired behaviour

```
safe_foo :: Maybe X -> Maybe Y -> Maybe Z
safe_foo Nothing _ = Nothing
safe_foo _ Nothing = Nothing
safe_foo (Just x) (Just y) = Just (foo x y)
```

what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need [liftA2](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:liftA2), which is defined as part of the `Applicative` type class.

```
safe_foo = liftA2 foo
```

Or alternatively, in the "applicative style":

```
safe_foo mx my = foo <$> mx <*> my
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use the monad with a `do` block

```
safe_foo mx my = do    -- BTW, we underscore_case is unconventional in Haskell,
   x <- mx             -- preferrably use camelCase instead
   y <- my
   return $ foo x y
```

...or, desugared&simplified,

```
safe_foo mx my = mx >>= (<$>my) . foo
```

but really you don't need `Monad` here, `Applicative` is enough.

```
safe_foo = liftA2 foo
```

or directly using the calc-functions,

```
   foo <$> calc1 a <*> calc2 b
```

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, where did `my` go in the desugared example?